How do I best scale png to 1 bit BMP (pyvips or PIL)
For a project I need to convert a PDF to strips of (large) BMP images, in 1 bit.
Quality is not the major issue here, but conversion speed is.
The input is a PDF document, the output is a series of BMP images, all around 65.000 x 4800 px.
I can't post the actual PDF, so as example I include a strip from the IKEA BILLY assembly instruction.

This strip is PNG format, but can also be JPG, PBM or others. Creation of strips is done using pyvips and is very fast.
Problem is how I get the final output. I know the command in ImageMagick, but it's painfully slow. Over 10 seconds per strip.
Imagemagick Command:
magick Billy_04.jpg -resize 65000x -dither FloydSteinberg -remap pattern:gray50 -colors 2 -monochrome BMP3:Billy_04_converted.bmp

I do not need any subsampling or similar, it's fine if the output is slight blocky.
Is there a way to do this conversion fast in Python ? I am not tied to pyvips.
The script I use to make the strips:
#!/usr/bin/python3

import sys
import pyvips
import math

destinationwidth = 60000
destinationheight = 4700

image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1])
for i in range(1):  # for the example, limit to first page only.
# for i in range(image.get('n-pages')):
    image = pyvips.Image.new_from_file(sys.argv[1], page=i, scale=10)
    mywidth = image.width
    myheight = image.height
    scale_in_width = destinationwidth/mywidth
    stripheight = math.floor(destinationheight/scale_in_width)
    stripcount = myheight/stripheight
    stripcountInt = math.ceil(stripcount)
    print("Width = " , mywidth, "  height = ", myheight)
    print("Strip height = ", stripheight, " amount of strips = ", stripcount , "  (round to) ", stripcountInt)

    theheight = stripheight
    verticalpos = 0
    for s in range(stripcountInt):

        print(f"Strip number {s} at {s*stripheight}  : ")
        thestrip = image.crop( 0, s*stripheight, mywidth, theheight)
        verticalpos += theheight

        # do not want to go outside area
        if (verticalpos + stripheight) > myheight:
            theheight = myheight - verticalpos-1

        thestrip.write_to_file(f"Pstrip_{s}.png")


Have you evaluate where the actual bottleneck is? I mean for a 65k×4.8k  image of 24 bits we are talking about roughly a GB of raw data.

No, I have not. But the resulting image is 65k x 4.8k in 1 bit, so 312.000.000 bit of data, or 39.000.000 byte.   I could possibly find external software to do the conversion, but if possible I would prefer to use Python direct.

You say you know the command in ImageMagick but don't show it?

Why are you writing the strip to a file as PNG? I thought you wanted a BMP? And have you considered multiprocessing?

If I could write the strips in a fast way directly in python as 1 bit bmp I would be very happy to do so. Problem is that I am missing the "convert to BMP 1 bit" part. If I write to bmp using pyvips, it comes out as 24 bit, and the scaling is very slow.

issys.argv[1] a raster graphic, or a vector graphic? -- BEFORE you convert to 1-bit, your picture IS huge. each single strip is huge, but what size is the entire page, after rasterization? -- profile your code. you need to know which parts take how long.

I got much faster results with NetPBM, like this magick billy.png -monochrome -scale 65000x pgm:- | pnmdepth 1 | ppmtobmp > me.bmp Not sure if that is any use for you.

if you know how to use ImageMagick then you can always use it in subprocess.run() in Python.. There is also Python module Wand which uses ImageMagick

libvips does not have a native BMP loader or saver -- for this format it'll go via libMagick, and won't give you much control over the save parameters.
Does it have to be BMP? If you can use 1-bit TIFF or 1-bit PNG instead, you can do this all in pyvips, and pyvips will automatically chunk it for you internally.
For example:
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import pyvips

image = pyvips.Image.pdfload(sys.argv[1])

# what scale do we need to get an image 65536 pixels across
target_width = 65536
scale = target_width / image.width

image = pyvips.Image.pdfload(sys.argv[1], scale=scale, page=5)

# the libvips pdf loader makes an rgba image ... flatten to rgb to remove the
# alpha, then convert to mono
image = image.flatten().colourspace("b-w")

# and save as 1-bit tiff
image.tiffsave(sys.argv[2], compression="ccittfax4", bitdepth=1)

With the billy PDF:
https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/assembly_instructions/billy-bookcase-white__AA-1823127-8-2.pdf
I can run:
$ VIPS_PROGRESS=1 /usr/bin/time -f %M:%e ./pdf-to-fax.py ~/pics/billy-bookcase-white__AA-1823127-8-2.pdf x.tif
pdf-to-fax.py temp-25: 65566 x 92730 pixels, 32 threads, 128 x 128 tiles, 640 lines in buffer
pdf-to-fax.py temp-25: done in 48.3s          
2420324:48.38
$ ls -l x.tif
-rw-r--r-- 1 john john 1012028 Jun 15 14:08 x.tif

The image looks OK:

It needs 2.4gb, which isn't great. libvips uses 4000 scanline-high chunks for pdfload, perhaps this ought to be a tunable parameter?
